# What difference in schema VS table VS column CHARSET in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, utf8mb4

What difference in schema CHARSET **VS** table CHARSET **VS** column CHARSET in MySQL?

When I change my table's charset to utf8, can I use utf8mb4 charset in my column?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Specifying a character set on database level is in fact defining the **default** character set for tables.

Doing the same for tables defines the **default** character set for columns.

Since you can't go further down the road, specifying a character set on a column will definitely use the character set for everything you store in that column.
When you don't specify a character set on column level, the character set of the table is used. And if that is not specified the character set of the database is used.

Answer (score 1):

When creating a table, the backup for charset and collation is the settings for the schema.

Once you have created the table, it now has a default charset and collation.  (This is subtly different than what fancyPants said.)

Similarly, when creating a column (either as part of creating the table, or with `ALTER .. ADD COLUMN`), you can be explicit about charset and collation, or it can inherit from the defaults given for the table.  Again, the column's definition is now frozen.

Doing `SHOW CREATE TABLE` will show an override or continue to leave the implicit inheritance.  `SELECT .. FROM information_schema.columns ..` makes it clearer that every column has a charset and collation.

That is, there is no "dynamic" inheritance at "run time".  The inheritance is only when the table or column is created.

Note that each charset has a default collation.  And each collation belongs to a specific charset (see the first part of the collation name).  So, specifying either the charset or collation implicitly specifies the other.